# finding all the values with given key for multimap

Tags: c++, multi-mapping, unordered-multimap

I am searching for all pairs for a particular key in a multimap using the code below.

```
int main() {
    multimap<int,int> mp;
    mp.insert({1,2});
    mp.insert({11,22});
    mp.insert({12,42});
    mp.insert({1,2});
    mp.insert({1,2});

    for (auto itr = mp.find(1); itr != mp.end(); itr++)
        cout << itr->first<< '\t' << itr->second << '\n';
}
```

Comment: `find` returns an iterator into the map where the element is found. It doesn't create something new with just the matched results.

Comment: This code must not do what you want it to do.  But you haven't mentioned what you want it to do, and that makes it rather difficult to "solve this".  The output is correct for the code you have written.

Comment: I want to search all the pairs with 1 as key. find(11) return {11,22} but it's not the case with find(1), it returns all the pairs.

Comment: Your code is written to find one iterator with a `1` key - which it does - and then iterate to the end of the container - which it does.  I suspect that you may be confused about what an iterator is (`itr`), or what it means to increment an iterator (`itr++`), or what `mp.end()` signifies.

Comment: @2k18_EC_157 The info you've posted in the comment is essential for understanding your actual problem+desired behaviour. If you notice there's confusion about what you're asking about, you should [edit] the question and add this info to the question itself. I've already added the info to the question in this case btw.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're calling `find` only a single time in your code. It's perfectly acceptable for this call to return the same value as `mp.begin()` resulting in you iterating though all the entries in the map before reaching `mp.end()`.

You can use the [`equal_range` member function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/equal_range) to get iterators for the start and end of the elements with key `1`:

```
for (auto[itr, rangeEnd] = mp.equal_range(1); itr != rangeEnd; ++itr)
{
    std::cout << itr->first<< '\t' << itr->second << '\n';
}
```

Comment: this is what i was looking for. Thanks. My mistake, I misunderstood the find function.

Answer (score 3):

Like others pointed out your code looped all the elements, from the first iterator (find(1) retuned the first iterator) to last.

If you want you can use C++20 ranges (`#include <ranges>`)

```
//DATA
std::multimap<int, int> mp;    
mp.insert({ 1,2 });
mp.insert({ 11,22 });
mp.insert({ 12,42 });
mp.insert({ 1,3 });
mp.insert({ 1,4 });

//FILTER THE ELEMENTS
auto foundElements = mp | std::views::filter([](auto& v) {
    return v.first == 1;
    });

//PRINT
for (auto m : foundElements)
{
    std::cout << m.first << " " << m.second << std::endl;
}
```